# Why can't a static member function have a const qualifier?

Tags: c++, static, language-lawyer, const-correctness, function-qualifier

Today I got a problem. I am in the need of a `static` member function, `const` is not a must but a better. But, I didn't succeed in my efforts. Can anybody say why or how?

Comment: What would a `const` static member function mean, to you?

Comment: @GMan I mean that a static member function which never changes any of it's inputs.

Comment: Then your inputs (function parameters) should be by value or const-references.

Comment: It doesn't affect the constness of the arguments of member functions anyway. It does not mean "make everything const", it means "make **this** const".

Comment: @GMan are you saying that const must be added to the arguments

Comment: @prab: For what you asked for, yes.

Comment: @Gman ya, you are correct. This did my need.

Comment: @GManNickG "What would a `const` static member function mean, to you?" - I understand `const` here means constness of `this` which isn't used for static calls, but for me it could easily mean "forbid modifications of static member data" and that would be useful IMO

Answer (score 176, accepted):

When you apply the `const` qualifier to a nonstatic member function, it affects the `this` pointer.  For a const-qualified member function of class `C`, the `this` pointer is of type `C const*`, whereas for a member function that is not const-qualified, the `this` pointer is of type `C*`.

A static member function does not have a `this` pointer (such a function is not called on a particular instance of a class), so const qualification of a static member function doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Does it mean that 'const' is only for variables like int,pointer,etc.?

Comment: @prabhakaran - Member functions can be **const** qualified too. James clearly mentioned it in his answer.

Comment: @Mahesh Member function's const qualifier also, qualifies only the 'this pointer', not the whole. You can still change the global variable within the const qualified member function. Now only I checked this.

Comment: I forgot to add this line at starting of the above "After practically checked Steve Jessop's(below) comment I have to say that"

Comment: Is it `C const*` or `const C*` ?

Comment: Shouldn't a const qualifier on member function makes "this" be of type "C const *const", since "this" by default is a constant pointer?

Comment: @crisron both are identical. In C/C++, whether or not you put the `const` qualifier for the innermost type on the left or right has no effect.

Comment: What if you want it to promise not to change any of the static members?

Comment: Both are identical, because `const` acts on what is on his LEFT. And if there is nothing on his left, acts on the first element on his Right. It's a common habit to write `const C*`, and it's OK. But the interpreted syntax is `C const *`.

Answer (score 30):

I agree with your question, but unfortunately the C++ is designed that way. For example:

```
class A {
  int i;         //<--- accessed with 'this'
  static int s;  //<---- accessed without 'this'
public:
  static void foo ()  const // <-- imaginary const
  {}
};
```

As of today, the `const` is considered in context of `this`. In a way, it's narrow. It can be made broader by applying this `const` beyond `this` pointer.
i.e. the "proposed" `const`, which may also apply to `static` functions, will restrict the `static` members from any modification.

In the example code, if `foo()` can be made `const`, then in that function, `A::s` cannot be modified. I can't see any language side effects, if this rule is added to standard. On the contrary, it's amusing that why such rule doesn't exist!

Comment: Probably the same as the reason that you can't const-modify a free function to mean "this function doesn't modify any global variables". `const` applies to an object (in the case of const member functions, the instance on which it's called). You want to make it apply to all static members of the class, I would guess that if it was considered at all by the committee, then it wasn't thought to be a common enough requirement to support.

Comment: The `const` modifier isn't applied to member methods or member variables, but to the implicit `this`-pointer. Since a static member method is not bound to an object there is no `this`-pointer to make `const`.

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunate that C++ doesn't accept it as per design but logically there are few use cases in which it validates well.

A function which is class level valid(static) might not change any static data, may be it will just query data should be const. 
May be it should be like

```
if(Object)
    MakeThisConstant()
else
    MakeStaticDataConstant() // Only in the scope but static data cannot be constant so may be it should in some scenarios
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the details, it's because there may or may not be an object modified by the function, so const is ambiguous to the compiler.

Recall that `const` keeps objects constant, but there may or may not be an object here to keep constant.

Comment: "may or may not"?  A static member function *never* has a `this` pointer.  (Besides which, `const` doesn't keep objects constant.  It prevents a particular pointer or reference from being used to modify the object, but modification might still happen through another path)

Answer (score 0):

A 'const member function' is not
allowed to modify the object it is called on, but static member
functions are not called on any object.
It is used directly by scope resolution operator.
Thus having a const static member function makes no sense, hence it is illegal.

Comment: static const have a good sense as just a scope binding to the class where it is defined, or to provide getter for global private fields.