# Why there is no concept of "const-correctness" for class's static member functions?

Tags: c++, static-members, const-correctness

Use case:

```
class A {
  static int s_common;
public:
  static int getCommon () const { s_common; };
};
```

Typically this results in an error as:

> error: static member function ‘static int A::getCommon()’ cannot have
>   cv-qualifier

This is because `const`ness applies only to the object pointed by `this`, which is not present in a `static` member function.

However had it been allowed, the `static` member function's "const"ness could have been easily related to the `static` data members.
Why is this feature is not present in C++; any logical reason behind it ?

Comment: @keety, [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035356/c-why-static-member-function-cant-be-created-with-const-qualifier) is related and not duplicate, I had seen that and upvoted it. The `this` pointer argument I have mentioned in my question also and it doesn't seem to be sufficient.

Comment: cool but maybe better if you link the original thread in the question to get a context or you mind end up with the same answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cv-qualifiers` affect the function's signature. So you could have:

```
class A {
  static int s_common;
public:
  static void getCommon () const {  };
  static void getCommon () {  };
};
```

Now... how would you call the `const` one? There's no `const` object to call it on (well, you could call it on a `const` object, but that's not the point).

I'm just guessing here, there probably are other reasons. :)

Comment: Such a combination could simply be considered illegal. I'm not sure its a good enough reason to rule out the possibility.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson why would it be illegal? The standard says you can overload by cv-qualifiers. Anything can be deemed illegal if we alter the rules enough.

Comment: -1 @Luchian: the new rules that would allow `static const` would have to make the overloading invalid, since it cannot easily be resolved except by casting. that's the why of it. so i think your answer was incorrectly selected as a solution: it is not a reason at all, just an associative misconception.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf of course you could modify the rules to make anything invalid. But this was just a guess (as noted in the answer itself). I don't think it's an invalid answer just because you can think of a way the rules can change to invalidate it.

Comment: Very good point, but as you suspected yourself, the actual reason is different. It is given in the answers by Nicol Bolas and Alok Save.

Answer (score 8):

> However had it been allowed, the static member function's "const"ness could have been easily related to the static data members.

This is where your question becomes confused. A non-static member function declared as `const` still has non-`const` access to *static* data members. The `const` only applies to `this` (ie: the non-static data members).

It would make no sense for a static member function to use `const` in the same way syntactically, yet have a completely different outcome (ie: making access to static data members `const`).

Furthermore, static data members are nothing more than class-scoped global variables that have class access controls (public/private/etc) on them. So it doesn't make sense for some functions to have different `const` access to them, especially based on their signature.

Answer (score 5):

The rationale for having `const` cv-qualifier on member functions is:
To indicate that the hidden pointer `this` being passed to the member function is immutable and it cannot be modified. A `static` member function does not have the hidden `this` parameter, and hence `const` for `static` member functions is meaningless.

**However had it been allowed, the static member function's "const"ness could have been easily related to the static data members.**

That was not the rationale for having `const` qualifier to begin with, this is evident from the fact that you cannot have cv-qualifiers applied to a free function. The `cv-qualifiers` were and are only meant for `this`, the object whose function is being called.

Comment: I have also deleted my comment since it has no meaning without your previous comment. I feel an infinite loop coming on. :))

Comment: Interesting, I had simply been thinking of the `const` as a way of stating the function wouldn't change the object. That means it's superfluous for a static function (since it *has* no object) but I can't see why it would be *disallowed* rather than just ignored.

Answer (score 2):

A function that doesn't change *any* global state is pure. C++11 introduces attributes that might include `[[pure]]` on particular platforms.

One problem with `const` is that it's part of the *type* of the function. Assigning that `static const` function to a "normal" function pointer would require a special conversion, cast, or decay rule. And as Luchian mentions, it would allow completely ambiguous overloading.

Essentially you are describing forming a singleton object from the `static` members, sharing a common, qualified indirect access path. For the non-const object to appear const, it must be accessed through something, but there's no `this`. Would its `decltype` change? There is no good answer. If you want all this, then put them explicitly inside a `class` object.

Comment: That's a good point. Is [[pure]] an extension ? I generally refer to [wiki link for C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), but couldn't find that by simple grep.

Comment: @iammilind `[[pure]]` is not standard, and I don't suppose any platform implements it. But GCC has `__attribute__((pure))` and MSVC has something similar, IIRC. Attributes are controversial and there may be a boycott among major implementations (see Herb Sutter's recent article) so things like `[[pure]]` might never be portable.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that using `static` and `const` on a member function to refer to constness of static member variables was simply never considered as an option. IMO your suggestion is kind of a strange (but maybe sensible) way of mixing those two keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

I believe conceptually const-ness applies to well-defined object or a data structure. Not to global/static or etc.

The same way I may ask why a global (or alternatively namespace-specific) function may not be `const`, i.e. it may promise not to modify any global (or namespace-specific) variables.

This doesn't make too much sense IMHO. But yes, const-ness of static members belonging to a specific class - this *might* be useful in some cases IMHO.